# GCP - BQ concatenate date and hr

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

select
day,hr
from  tabledb.tablename

day = 02/12/2024
hr = 13

I want to concate/format the value into timestamp.
TO_TIMESTAMP(concat(DAY, ' ',HR, ':00:00'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
Can some one suggest

Comment: what you mean by **"Can some one suggest"** ?

Comment: Asking somebody in the group can suggest some options..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want. I am assuming you have two columns. one has date and another has time. and you want to form a timestamp.

```sql
SELECT
  DATETIME_ADD(CAST (t.d AS datetime FORMAT "YYYY/MM/DD"), INTERVAL CAST(t.h AS int) HOUR)
FROM (
  SELECT "2021/01/01" AS d, "13" AS h ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M', FORMAT('%s %s:00', d, h)) AS ts
FROM (SELECT "2021/01/01" AS d, "13" AS h)
```

with output

[image]